# TSUP declaration files keeping project structure

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I am trying to use TSUP to bundle my React UI library. I have this configuration currently.

```
import type { Options } from 'tsup';

const tsup: Options = {
    splitting: true,
    clean: true,
    dts: true,
    format: ['esm'],
    minify: true,
    bundle: true,
    skipNodeModulesBundle: true,
    target: 'es2020',
    outDir: 'dist',
    entry: ['src/**/*.tsx'],
    esbuildOptions(options) {
        // the directory structure will be the same as the source
        options.outbase = "./";
    },
};

export default tsup
```

I am currently getting all of the `tsx` files compiled and structured the same as the in the project. How do I get the `.d.ts` files to be in the same directory as the components?

Comment: How did you prevent tsup from bundling the files into one index file?